# How to disable/remove IDFA tool(s) from Expo project

Tags: react-native, mobile, app-store, expo

I am submitting react native(expo) project  to app store. I got to the step where I am told that my app uses IDFA and I had to tick some boxes so that I can confirm that I am using them which in fact is not true.
From research I found out that expo uses analytics tools like Segment and Amplitude which is built in.

I would really prefer to say that I am not using the IDFA and I do not plan to use it in at all. How can I disable IDFA usage in my binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into the same problem and I found this [issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1320) on the expo repository. It seems that right now it isn't possible to do that, so the easiest thing to do is check those boxes when submitting the app.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for the answer. That is my issue btw :), Did that, just checked the boxes.